# react does not render all elements although my state has changed

Tags: reactjs, loops, state, rendering

Hi I am implementing a web conference room with web Socket and webRTC. I store the users in the `connectionList`. Whenever a user connects, then a user is added to the list.  Only remote users are stored. Accordingly, another video and audio element should be created when a new user joins the meeting.

For example, if the meeting room has 3 users, then 2 remote users are stored in the list. This means that the video and audio element should be created 2x. The list has 2 elements, but only one video and one audio element will be created. Only when I save the application and cause another render, all elements appear.
Here is important part of code.

```
          {connectionList.map((stream, index) => (

            <React.Fragment key = {stream.id}>
              <div>{console.log("div index:", index)}</div>
              <video ref={el => {
                console.log("index in ref", index);
                console.log("connectionList", connectionList);
                if (index >= remoteVideoStreamList.current.length) {
                  remoteVideoStreamList.current.push({
                    stream: el,
                    fromUserID: connectionList[index].fromUserID
                  });
                }
              }} autoPlay style={{
                height: `${250}px`,
                width: `${250}px`,
                border: `solid ${1}px black`
              }} ></video>
              <audio ref={el => {
                if (index >= remoteAudioStreamList.current.length) {
                  remoteAudioStreamList.current.push({
                    stream: el,
                    fromUserID: connectionList[index].fromUserID
                  });
                }
              }} autoPlay ></audio>
            </React.Fragment>
          ))}
```

I have console logs to see how far the index goes and how many elements the list has. Likewise I have a div to check again how far the index goes. I have the following output

```
App.jsx:325 div index: 0
App.jsx:327 index in ref 0
App.jsx:328 connectionList Array(2)
```

When rendering again later

```
App.jsx:325 div index: 0
App.jsx:325 div index: 1
```

The video element is skipped even though the list has 2 elements. Only when I save, then all elements are created. I hope someone can help me

I have searched the internet why elements are not drawn. Maybe it's the key, but I don't get an error message. When I save, all the elements appear, so it can't be the key. With

```
useEffect(()=>{
   console.log("changed");
   console.log(connectionList)
 },[connectionList])
```

I have seen that the state really changes. That's why I don't have a clue what the error could be.

Comment: Make sure you are not pushing new items to the `connectionList` array directly, but always use the `setConnectionList` setter.

Comment: So the list is extended by one user each time a user joins the room. Then it should be directly re-rendered and another video element should show up.

Comment: Right. You just can't push items directly as `connectionList.push(newUser)`. Instead, you should modify your state as `setConnectionList((prev) => [...prev, newUser])`

Comment: This was likely due to the fact that you were calling `setConnectionList` in a `useEffect` and the value for `connectionList` had not been updated at the time, hence why using the internal state (grabbed from `(prev) => ... ` ) resolved the issue

Comment: In my code I do ```setConnectionList(...connectionList, stackConnection)```. tackConnection stores from all connection messages the users and put them at the end in the state. When I chnage it to ```setConnectionList((prev)=>[...prev, stackConnection])``` it works but I don't get the list that I want. I get a list with lists. But it helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for the solution in the comments. So that other users can see the coder better here is the solution

Instead of changing the state like this

```
setConnectionList(...connectionList, stackConnection)
```

(stackConnection ist eine locale liste)

The state must be changed like this. Then it works

```
setConnectionList((prev) => ([...prev, {
          fromUserID: msgDispatcher.fromUserID,
          connection: pc,
          id: uuid()
        }]));
```